# Android SDK installed but not found

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm installing an environment for an Ionic project on Windows 10. I downloaded Android studio and installed SDK in 
`C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`

My system variable `ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`

Executed OK:
ionic platform add android

But :

```
$ ionic run android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\KGE\SVN\trunk\sagaMobile\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js C:/Users/KGE/SVN/trunk/sagaMobile
add to body class: platform-android
Error: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

I tried to find a solution for 2 days but nothing works. If you have any ideas ...

EDIT: 
I use Git bash for input. I have the same with CMD, even as admin.

EDIT 2: 
Solved by removing and reinstall of the whole project

Comment: Those are Windows paths and prompt $ looks like a Bash one. Can you explain your environment setup?

Comment: shouldn't your ANDROID_HOME BE : C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk?

Comment: I use Git bash for input. I have the same with CMD, even as admin.